# Failure for config changes in Magento to take effect

Tags: magento

I've inherited a projected involving a fairly large Magento store with no handover and no line of communication with the previous developer.

I have been teaching myself Magento for a few days and I feel I have a reasonable appreciation of it.

The main task I have to do is to create a new design for the front end, which seems straight forward enough to do through a theme. As there was only one website set up in magento, I created another as a test environment.

The issue I have, is that any change I make to configuration settings seem to take effect intermittently. I have disable cache, but still have the problem.

Specifically, at the moment, template path hints on are turned on. After turning them for the test website (where they are enabled), they still appear. This change was made half an hour ago, i have manually cleared cache on both the site and the browser.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the clearest explanation but these usually help:

Have you disabled the Merge of JS and CSS files in `system > configuration > Advanced > Developer` ?
After you've done that you need to flush the JS and CSS (Same page you turned off your cache)

Also if you're making Category & Product changes you should reindex data in`System > Index Management`

Make sure the compilation is disabled as well `system > tools > compilation`

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the poor explanation, I'm new to Magento and so am unsure as to what the important information to report is.

Turning of the merge of JS and CSS worked - allowing my changes to appear instantly. Exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check the compiler is off too, although that shouldn't affect the template hints. Also check that there aren't any other caches such as an HTML cache at the webserver. And do flush the Magento Cache and Cache Storage too.

I think the main thing you need to look at is the 'Current Configuration Scope:' in the top-left of the Magento Admin System->Configuration page. That drop-down will control which 'website' you are setting config values for.

If it isn't that, please try to give more information about your set up; I didn't really understand your setup from your question. I recommend you set up a second server as your development server rather than a second website in an existing setup.

I would also add that the RWD theme in Magento 1.9 is an excellent theme and you might want to consider modifying that theme.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Turning the merging of CSS and JS files worked in the end. I did set up a second server, however the previous dev has added so many addons and made changes which make me worried that a theme wouldn't translate across well. The DB is so huge, I've had trouble exporting and importing it to another server. the dump is 2gb, so importing it has been problematic. Excellent tip on RWD theme too, I should have mentioned, editing it is what I'm doing, not starting from scratch. Thank you.

Comment: The large database is probably due to bloated log tables - you could truncate those tables before exporting and you can also truncate the core_url_rewrites table which may also have grown large. (then regenerate it by re-indexing via the Magento Admin)